# Wolfram Alpha's Complex Integration involving Log in the antideriviative, gives a different result

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I need to compute:

$$ I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{i}{9 e^{i 2 \theta} + 1}d\theta $$

The indefinite integral above is:

$$ F(\theta)= i \theta - \frac{1}{2} \log(1 + 9 e^{2 i \theta}) $$

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bi%2F%283%5E2+e%5E%28+i+2t%29+%2B+1%29%2C%7Bt%2C+-Pi%2F2%2C+Pi%2F2%7D%5D) and my own computation.

The problem is that if I assign the values of the limit myself to it I get:

$$ F(\frac{\pi}{2}) - F(-\frac{\pi}{2}) = \\
i (\frac{\pi}{2} - (-\frac{\pi}{2}))-\frac{1}{2} \left (\log(1+9 e^{2 i\frac{\pi}{2}}) -\log(1+9e^{2 i \cdot (-\frac{\pi}{2})}\right ) = \\
i \pi -\frac{1}{2}\left ( \log(\frac{1-9}{1-9})\right ) = i\pi
$$

And wolfram's solution for the definite integral is $0$ ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bi%2F%283%5E2+e%5E%28+i+2t%29+%2B+1%29%2C%7Bt%2C+-Pi%2F2%2C+Pi%2F2%7D%5D)).

Why? Is it related to the principal value of the natural logarithm?

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of copy & paste, but you always wrote $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} $

Comment: Thanks @Raffaele, it was a mistake indeed. Edited the question.

Comment: The first integral you wrote in terms of $\theta$ evaluates to $-i\pi$ in Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica. So I guess something must have gone wrong between that and the integral $I_2$ that you entered.

Comment: @sal I understand your point, but I think not. Because: Say $I = I_1 + I_2$ Than according to wolfram, $I = - i \pi = I_1 = I_1 + I_2$ and $I_2 = 0$. The problem as I see it is that only under my calculation $I_2 = +i \pi$ where under wolfram's calculation $I_2 = 0$.

Comment: Is the differential in the integration $dz$ or $d\theta$?  Seems to not be well defined, or not precisely defined.

Comment: Thanks @mjw I edited the question.

Comment: @GEdgar $\gamma$ is a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely related to the natural logarithm. When $\theta=-\pi/2$ we may take the argument to be $9(-1)+1=8e^{-\pi i}$. As $\theta$ increases from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, $9e^{2i\theta}+1$ circles the point $z=1$ counterclockwise in the complex $z$-plane so that when $\theta=0$ it will be $10e^{i0}$ and by the time $\theta=\pi/2$ it will be $8e^{\pi i}$ so
$$F(\pi/2)-F(-\pi/2)=\left(i\frac{\pi}2-\frac12\left(\pi i+\ln8\right)\right)-\left(-i\frac{\pi}2-\frac12\left(-\pi i+\ln8\right)\right)=0$$
Since the magnitude is never $0$ the phase must change continuously.

**EDIT:** Another way to think about it to say that
$$\begin{align}F(\theta)&=i\theta-\frac12\ln\left(1+9e^{2i\theta}\right)\\
&=-\frac12\ln\left(e^{-2i\theta}\right)-\frac12\ln\left(1+9e^{2i\theta}\right)=-\frac12\ln\left(e^{-2i\theta}+9\right)\end{align}$$
And now as $\theta$ changes the path doesn't circle a branch point so it's not so critical to think about the phase of the argument of the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{z^3}{z^2+1}=z\frac{z^2}{z^2+1}=z\left(1-\frac{1}{z^2+1}\right)=z-\frac{z}{z^2+1}$$
$$\int zdz=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}3e^{i\theta}d\theta$$
$$\int\frac{z}{z^2+1}dz=\frac12\int\frac{1}{u}du$$
$u=z^2+1=9e^{2i\theta}+1$

Comment: The second integral ($\int \frac{1}{u}du$) is zero for the limits at hand right? And the 1st integral evaluates to 6 and not $-i \pi$.

Comment: I take back my previous comment. The problem with the 1st integral is that it was not evaluated correctly - $dz \ne d\theta$ but: $dz = i 3e^{i\theta} d\theta$. Meaning that $\int_{\gamma} z dz = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} i (3 e^{i\theta})^2 = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} 9 i e^{i 2 \theta} = 0$